# Matlab: out of memory for 3 D matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am N = 10^6 data points and want to create (a) a N by N 2D matrix,A (b) and assign the values of P into the third dimension of a 3D matrix B. For N = 256 to N =1000, the following works

```
A = 0.1*eye(N,N);
 B(:,:,1) =A;
```

But for higher values of N, I am getting out of memory error. So, I found that I can create a sparse matrix instead of using eye as `A = 0.1*eye(N,N);` But then B cannot be created as that operation does not work for sparse. How can I find a way out? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cell arrays.

```
B=cell(1000000);
B{1}=A;
```

This is for memory storage only.I don't know what you are going to do finally.
Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and please accept my apology for not explaining more. The matrix A is used for calculating the covariance in Kalman filter and B is the smoothed covariance matrix obtained after applying Kalman Smoother. The solution does not work in this case and throws error as cat error.